# instancing behaviour in a wcf per session service with shared members

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, instance

Here is my scenario: 
I have a wcf service hosted in IIS.
The wcf service consistes of two main classes: MyWcf and MyClass.
MyWcf consists of all the service endpoints:

```
<ServiceContract(SessionMode:=SessionMode.Allowed)> Public Interface IMyWcf
    <OperationContract()> Function GetListing As DataTable
End Interface
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)> Public Class MyWcf
    Implements IMyWcf
    Public Function GetListing As DataTable Implements IMyWcf.GetListing
        Return MyClass.GetSomeDataTable
    End Function
End Class
```

MyClass contains all shared members

```
Friend Class MyClass
    Friend Shared Function GetSomeDataTable As DataTable
        'some code
    End Function
End Class
```

The thing i want to be sure of is this:  with this setup, if two clients call the GetListing function at the same time are they both using the same instance of the GetSomeDataTable function (because the function is shared) or do both clients end up getting different/unique instances of GetSomeDataTable function (and all other shared members in MyClass)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Techniques For Developing WCF Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S2)

Windows Communication Foundation can maintain a private session
between a client and a particular service instance. When the client
creates a new proxy to a service configured as session-aware, the
client gets a new dedicated service instance that is independent of
all other instances of the same service.